# who has an idea about PhoneGap storage

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to develop an android application, and this script will copy a database table on my phone, but after the execution he displays this error below

```
//---------------Copier-------------------------    

 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://10.0.2.2:1998/bYzance_web_service/get_all_PhrasesTypes.asmx/Get_all_PrasesTypes",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async : false,
         success: function (data)
          {
             alert("success: function (data)");

             var result = $.parseJSON(data.d); 

             alert(result[0].Phrase);

             for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
             {                 
                 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO PhrasesTypes (idPhrase,idPhraseES,idRubrique,idTypeTravauxAffichage,Phrase,AidePhrase,AvertissementPhrase,OrdrePhrase,QuotationParDefaut,Published)"
+  " VALUES ('"+result[i].IdPhrase+"',' "+result[i].IdPhraseES+" ',' "+result[i].IdRubrique+" ',' "+result[i].IdTypeTravauxAffichage+" ','"+mysql_real_escape_string(result[i].Phrase)+"',' "+result[i].AidePhrase+" ',' "+result[i].AvertissementPhrase+" ','"+result[i].OrdrePhrase+"','"+result[i].QuotationParDefaut+"','"+result[i].Published+" ')");
       console.log(i);
    }

         },
         error: function (e)
          {
            alert("URL du web service:  "+serviceURL+"get_all_PhrasesTypes.asmx/Get_all_PrasesTypes");

         }

     });//fin Ajax
```

> sqlite returned : error code =1, msg near "accunedifined" : syntax
>   error

Comment: You are allowed to put line breaks in your code, even in the part that generates an SQL statement. :)

Comment: You also got spaces around some values, which I think is an error, like this: `'...' "+result[i].AidePhrase+" '...'`. This will put spaces inside the string value of AidePhrase.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the statement is invalid. You just add up strings, and even use the function `mysql_real_escape_string`, which is a PHP function, unless you have defined it in Javascript as well. If any of those strings contain an invalid character, especially a `'`, your statement will become invalid.

The best thing to do, is find a way to view the generated SQL. You will probably spot the error right away, but if not, you can post that generated SQL here, so we can take a look.

Comment: yes i have mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: That's only one of the potential issues. Like I asked: what is the generated insert statement?

Comment: the problem is because of the special characters, which is why I use the develop by myself to call (mysql_real_escape_string) to remove special characters. does anyone has another idea to remove characters spécaiux?

Comment: I understand that. So please listen to what I say: View the generated SQL string. There must be an error in there. Just log it, view it, post it here... Help me help you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to console.log the `result` array values. I think you have a chance that some values contain a single quote which make the string SQL invalid. Look for a `'accunedifined` in your results

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mysql_real_escape_string` after you copy your PHP code into JavaScript.

Comment: the problem is because of the special characters, which is why I use the develop by myself to call (mysql_real_escape_string) to remove special characters. does anyone has another idea to remove characters spécaiux?

Comment: the problem is because of the special characters, which is why I use the develop by myself to call (mysql_real_escape_string) to remove special characters. does anyone has another idea to remove characters spécaiux?

Answer (score 0):

In you `mysql_real_escape_string`, add some logic to duplicate the single quotes:

```
// Note: replaceAll doesn't work, you need to implement it
str = str.replaceAll("'","''");
```

Some `replaceAll` ideas:
[Replace all strings in dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678742/replace-all-strings-in-dom-element)