# JS how right replace element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```
...
<div>
   <div>
      {FirstName} {POSITION}
   </div>
</div>
...
```

We would like find element `{FirstName}` and repalce him on `test`.

For this we make:

```
$("{FirstName}").replaceWith("test");
```

But it is not working...

Tell me please how right make replace?

Comment: elements are HTML elements, Text nodes can not be selected by their content

Comment: @raam86 cannot do a search text {FirstName} in the dom?

Comment: Try this function: [searchAndReplace](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/). Here is a demo of how it works with your given situation: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/ynv1yqju/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is target the parent DIV (lets pretend it has a class of .test)

```
var content = $('.test').html();
var new_content = content.replace('{Whatever}', 'Hello');
$('.test').html(new_content);
```

Or in short (I haven't tested this, but it should work)

```
$('.test').html($('.test').html().replace('{Whatever}', 'Hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace a string in DOM elements, the question has been asked before :

[Replace all strings in dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678742/replace-all-strings-in-dom-element)

But best to do this would be to use a template engine.